# Let $U(a,t) = \{a\} \cup [t, \infty)$ where $a,t \in \Bbb R.$ Show that the sets of form $U(a,t)$ form a basis for some topology on $\Bbb R$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $U(a,t) = \{a\} \cup [t, \infty)$ where $a,t \in \Bbb R.$ Show that the sets of form $U(a,t)$ form a basis for some topology on $\Bbb R$.

Since they're asking to show that these sets form *some* topology for $\Bbb R$ I think I should show that $\bigcup \{U(a,t) \mid a,t \in \Bbb R\}$ covers $\Bbb R$ and that the intersection $U(a,t) \cap U(b,s)$ is either empty or in $\bigcup \{U(a,t) \mid a,t \in \Bbb R\}$?

I think the first part is clear, but not sure how to show this since it does seem that I would need to vary $a,t$ both so would I have something like $$\bigcup_{a,t \in \Bbb R} \{a\} \cup[t,\infty) = \Bbb R?$$

Also for the latter I think I have several cases to consider. I have $$(\{a\} \cup [t, \infty)) \cap (\{b\} \cup[s, \infty)) = \{a \} \cup[t, \infty)$$ if $a \le b \le t \le s$. Also if $b \le a \le s \le t$, then $$(\{a\} \cup [t, \infty)) \cap (\{b\} \cup[s, \infty)) = \{b\} \cup[s, \infty)$$

but I think there are other cases to consider also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, if $x \in \Bbb R$ we can for sure say that $x \in U(x,t)$ whatever $t$ is. So the collection $\mathcal{B}=\{U(a,t)\mid a,t \in \Bbb R\}$ covers $\Bbb R$.

The second condition is (in formal form)

$$\forall B_1,B_2 \in \mathcal{B}: \forall z \in B_1 \cap B_2:\exists B_3 \in \mathcal{B}: z \in B_3 \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$$

So consider two sets $U(a_1,t_1), U(a_2,t_2) \in \mathcal{B}$ and suppose $z \in U(a_1,t_1) \cap U(a_2,t_2)$.

It's then clear that $z \in U(z,\max(t_1,t_2)) \subseteq U(a_1,t_1) \cap U(a_2,t_2)$; just check the definitions.

So the condition is satisfied. No cases required (you never have to check the case of empty intersection of base elements because that would satisfy the condition voidly..)

Comment: Note that $U(a,s) \cap U(b,t)$ always contains $u=\max(s,t)$ and all larger elements. They always intersect “big”.